# Can't utilize Folder content type in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, contenttype

I have a site on which I have unsealed and added columns to a content type, 'Folder'.  Now, I want to add this content type to a document library, but I do not have the option to add it in Document Library Settings -> Add from existing site content types.  I'm not seeing the "Folder Content Types" in the Groups drop-down menu.  Also, if I move the content type to another group that does show up in this drop-down, it still doesn't appear.  Is there something I have to do to make this content type a choice for my document library or a place to choose which content type groups are usable for a site?

Thanks very much

Comment: Have a look at the site using SharePoint Manager. It will tell you categorically if the Folder content type has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your own content type and it is published/activated to SharePoint, then it should be available for you to add to a Document Library. Just be sure that your document library is configured to support content types.

In the Advanced Settings section of Document Library Settings, select `Yes` under `Allow management of content types?` Then continue as you were. *Settings -> Add from existing site content types..*

You can use a console application (ref [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543576.aspx)) to add content type to a list on your site. It also gives you useful messages about the current state of things.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://YOUR_SPSITE")) {
            using (SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb() {

                // Get a content type.
                SPContentType ct = site.AvailableContentTypes["YOUR_CONTENT_NAME"];

                // The content type was found.
                if (ct != null) 
                    // Get a list.
                    try {
                        SPList list = site.Lists["YOUR_DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME"]; // Throws exception if does not exist.

                        // Make sure the list accepts content types.
                        list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

                        // Add the content type to the list.
                        if (!list.IsContentTypeAllowed(ct))
                            Console.WriteLine("The {0} content type is not allowed on the {1} list",
                                                ct.Name, list.Title);
                        else if (list.ContentTypes[ct.Name] != null)
                            Console.WriteLine("The content type name {0} is already in use on the {1} list",
                                                ct.Name, list.Title);
                        else
                            list.ContentTypes.Add(ct);
                    } 
                    catch (ArgumentException ex) // No list is found.                         
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The list does not exist.");
                    }
                else // No content type is found.
                    Console.WriteLine("The content type is not available in this site.");
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```